# SQL - Nested result instead of merge when left join

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, arrays, json

I have a SQL LEFT JOIN like this:

```
var getEmail = req.body.email;

const connection = require('../conig/db');
let promise = await new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    connection.query("SELECT users.id, users.account_id, users.email, accounts.id, accounts.company FROM users LEFT JOIN accounts ON accounts.id=users.account_id WHERE users.email = ?",[getEmail], function(err, rows) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            resolve();
        }
        console.log('rows:');
        console.log(rows);
        resolve();
    });
});
```

The result merges the columns:

```
[{
    id: 1,
    account_id: '1',
    email: 'user01@domain',
    company: 'Company 01'
}, {
    id: 3,
    account_id: '3',
    email: 'user02@domain',
    company: 'Company 02'
}, {
    id: null,
    account_id: '',
    email: 'user03@domain',
    company: null
}]
```

But what I would like to have is a nested result with the table name at first level like this:

```
[{
  users: {
    account_id: '1',
    email: "user01@domain",
    id: 1
  },      
  accounts: {
    company: "Company 01",
    id: 1
  }
}, {
  users: {
    account_id: '3',
    email: "user02@domain",
    id: 2
  },
  accounts: {
    company: "Company 03",
    id: 3
  }
}, {
  users: {
    account_id: '',
    email: "user03@domain",
    id: 3
  },      
  accounts: {
    company: null,
    id: null
  }
}]
```

How can I achieve this?

I tried:

```
SELECT users.id AS users.id, users.account_id AS users.account_id, users.email AS users.email, accounts.id AS accounts.id, accounts.company AS accounts.company FROM users LEFT JOIN accounts ON accounts.id=users.account_id
-> Error
```

Comment: How are you serializing the "users " and "accounts " classes and how are you instantiating them from the query results?

Comment: Anyway, try creating a cursor for the "users" and for each "user", make a script for the "accounts", filling a temporary table with this information to populate a "UserAccounts" class that has two properties ("User user" and "List<Account> accounts").

Comment: @RicardoRodrigues I don't understand what you mean by 'serializing' or 'creating a cursor', sorry ... I updated the query above ... its within a node.js mysql query

Comment: Well you are trying to get a json table, soo...serializaing one object does the trick. In your script, you are listing users and the correpondent accounts when I guess you should list all users and then, for each user, "attach" the accounts. You can achieve this with MySQL cursor that allows row-by-row processing of the result sets.

Comment: Can you provide an example below? Happy to accept your answer afterwards. Anyhow, thanks for the hints, I'll try to read more into those topics ...